# What could cause gettimerid() to fail, setting errno to ENOSPC (undocumented)?

Tags: c, aix

I am using AIX 6.1.  A program I am using (and involved in the development of) contains calls to the C library `gettimerid()` function.

The problem I am having is that `gettimerid()` calls have started intermittently failing perhaps once per day, returning -1 (indicating an error), and when I check `errno`, it has been set to `ENOSPC` (28d), meaning "No space left on device".

According to [the AIX documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/gettimerid.htm), `ENOSPC` is not shown as one of the possible return values, leaving me confused as to what this means.

As far as I am aware, this does not require any file system space, but I checked the unused file space and inode usage of the file systems, and these seemed to be fine with plenty available, and as far as I can tell there is plenty of free memory (although there may be some limit of this particular process I am not aware of, if this is relevant), so I am not sure what could cause `ENOSPC` to be returned as a result of a `gettimerid()` call.

Example code:

```
static timer_t TimerId;

if ( ( TimerId = gettimerid(TIMEOFDAY, 0) ) < 0 )
{
  printf( "gettimerid fail [timer id=%d, errno=%d]", TimerId, errno );
}
```

Example Output:

```
gettimerid fail [timer id=-1, errno=28]
```

Does anyone know what might cause this return code from `gettimerid()` on AIX?

Comment: Your code snippet and its output are not matching. In the code, you have the last character as - `[` (`errno=%d[`) in the `format` string of `printf()` but in the output, the last character is `]` (`errno=28]`). Make sure that the output belongs the same code that you have shown.

Comment: It is a simplified version of the code, and there was obviously a typo there.  Corrected.

Comment: Please check again your AIX version (`oslevel -r` or similar command)

Comment: Make sure to compile _everything_ with option `-D_THREAD_SAFE` (and `-pthread` if necessary)

Comment: Corrected, AIX 6.1, thanks.  Do you have any particular thoughts on why the compile flags you recommend would change this?  Why you think it might be thread issues?  I would be interested to read them if you have any links.  Also, are you proposing this as an answer?

Comment: No, it's just a little step toward cleaner code. See this: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0028
Also Timer_id might or might not be compatible with int, so you should use typecast when printf-ing it with '%d'

Comment: Thanks. Again, this is just a simplified example.  The errno and the fact that the return value is less than zero are the points that are relevant, I think (showing an error occurred).  I am not really as interested in the printf, but more about why the timer can fail, and what would be indicated by ENOSPC as an errno.

Comment: Was going to say I'm having the same problem, but turns out I'm looking at the same code as you!  Hi Dan :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be caused by repeatedly getting the `TIMEOFDAY` timer without calling `reltimerid` in between.  As an example to cause it:

```
 while( 1 )
 {
   timer_t TimerId;
   if( ( TimerId = gettimerid( TIMEOFDAY, 0 ) ) < 0 )
   {
     printf( "gettimerid failed: %d\n", errno );
     break;
   }
   else
     printf( "gettimerid OK: %d\n", TimerId );
 }
```

Output from this loop is:

```
gettimerid OK: 5
gettimerid OK: 6
gettimerid OK: 7
gettimerid OK: 8
gettimerid failed: 28
```

Which is the undocumented `ENOSPC` errno.